# Using jQuery to find and replace wildcard text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rather new to jQuery / JS and wondering how to do the following:

```
Big Sofa - Pink
Big Sofa - Blue
Small Sofa - Red
Small Sofa - Grey
```

What I need to do is remove all the text before and including the "-" so it just shows the colour, need to wildcard it so will get anything and replace with nothing.

Is this possible?

Comment: The best way to do this depends entirely on how the HTML is structured around these values. Could you please edit the question to include more of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using regex.
Here's example when you're using span for each entry:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("span").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    
    text = text.replace(/(\w+\s)+-\s/g, "");
    $(this).text(text);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Sofa test - red</span>
<span>Table test - blue</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this simple one

```
var a = "Big Sofa - Pink\nBig Sofa - Blue\nSmall Sofa - Red\nSmall Sofa - Grey"

var newA = a.split( "\n" ).map( function(value){ return value.split( "-" ).pop() } ).join( "\n" );

console.log( newA );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use regular expressions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

```
var text = 'Big Sofa - Pink';

var color = text.replace(/^.+?- (\w+)$/i, '$1'); // Pink
```

`^` matches the start of the string
`.` matches any character, including white space
`+` indicates that the preceding matcher have to occur 1 or more times
`?` after a multiplier indicates that the matching is non greedy (matches the minimum possible)
`-` matches literally a dash and a space
`(\w+)` matches any word composed by 1 or more word characters (letters, numbers and underscore) and capture its value in a group (group 1 in this case)
`$` matches the end of the string
`i` (at the end) indicates that the match is case insensitive

The replace string (`$1`) replaces the entire match by the content of the capture group 1. In our case it matches the color.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will work on multiline strings:

```
var str  = 'Big Sofa - Pink\nBig Sofa - Blue\nSmall Sofa - Red\nSmall Sofa - Grey';

str.replace(/.+\-\s*/g, '').split(/\n/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
var text = "Big Sofa - Pink";
var color = text.substring(text.indexOf("-") + 1)
```